# Sequential coloring of the <h1> tag by generator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to iterate through my list of colors and display them to my
h1 tag which has the Id name of id='Follow'. Could someone be kind enough to
assist me with this problem I am having?

```
 function colorScheme() {
  var hash = '#';
  var colorHex = ['00BFB2', '1A5E63', '028090', 'F0F3BD', '#C64191'];
  for (var i = 0; i < colorHex.length; i++) {
    hash += colorHex[Math.floor(Math.random())];
  }
  return hash;
}

function chooseColor() {
  var reference = colorScheme();
  Follow.style.color = reference;
}

setInterval('chooseColor()', 300);
```

Comment: You want to change the color of same h1 tag in given time interval?

Comment: setInterval takes a function, not a string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue in the way you pick a random number. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range) for more info on how to pick a random int in a range.

```js
 function colorScheme() {
  var colorHex = ['00BFB2', '1A5E63', '028090', 'F0F3BD', 'C64191'];
  var randomIndex =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (colorHex.length));
  return '#' + colorHex[randomIndex];
}

function chooseColor() {
  var reference = colorScheme();
  console.log(reference);
  document.getElementById('follow').style.color = reference;
}

setInterval(chooseColor, 300);
```

```html
<div id="follow">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: If my answer is what you were looking for, please set it as accepted. If it's not, please let me know what is wrong. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can instead of `page load` use `css animation`  and `keyframes`

as well you will be able to control timing

you will find in the snippet the `coloring keyframs`

```css
@keyframes coloring {
    0%{color:#000;}
    20%{color:#00BFB2;}
    40%{color:#1A5E63;}
    60%{color:#028090;}
    80%{color:#F0F3BD;}
    100%{color:#C64191;}
}

#follow{
 -webkit-animation: coloring 5s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:   coloring 5s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      coloring 5s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         coloring 5s infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}
```

```html
<h1 id="follow">Hello world</h1>
```

Comment: I appreciate you pitching in :)